# Dataframe removes duplicate when certain values ​are reached

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains duplicates. and I would like to remove these duplicates. I also found this function from pandas `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Action', 'Name'])`.
Unfortunately, this function removes too much, because only if the time is less than or equal to 5 minutes should it be removed.

How can I do this and how could I print how many rows are dropped? I would be very happy about help.

- How can you recognize duplicates?  If the columns (action, name) are identical and the time difference is less than or equal to 5 minutes.

---

**!** The time format is `01.10.2019, 9:56:52` date and time are splitted by a comma

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 9:56:52', '01.10.2019, 9:57:15', '02.10.2019 12:56:12', '02.10.2019 13:02:58', '02.10.2019 13:11:58']
     ,'Action': ['Opened', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Opened']
     ,'Name': ['Max', 'Max', 'Susan', 'Michael', 'Michael']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head())
```

### Output

[image]

### Desired Output

[image]

### Details

[image]

Comment: good use of images here to compliment your post

Comment: @Manakin Thanks, I'll do my best to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can create a `group` number by getting the time difference, and then `groupby` and `first`:

```
print (df.assign(group=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).diff().dt.seconds.gt(300).cumsum())
         .groupby(["group", "Action", "Name"]).first())

                      Time  Action     Name
group                                      
0      01.10.2019, 9:56:52  Opened      Max
1      02.10.2019 12:56:12  Closed    Susan
2      02.10.2019 13:02:58  Opened  Michael
3      02.10.2019 13:11:58  Opened  Michael
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! That worked. 
Is there still a way to get the number of rows deleted? In the example above, only one line would be deleted, ie `[IN] print(amount_deleted_rows) [OUT] 1`

Comment: Hmm, I guess you can do `len(old_df) - len(new_df)`?

Comment: Yes of course! I completely forgot. Thank you again for your clean solution. Wish you all the best!

Comment: This might be incorrect as you only group on Time, and not consider Action or Name. But it’s up to OP to decide.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum()` on the threshold differences to identify the group and groupby on that:

```
groups = (df.groupby(['Action', 'Name'])['Time']
                 .transform(lambda x: x.diff().gt('5min').cumsum())
              )
df.groupby([groups,'Action','Name'], as_index=False).head(1)
```

Output:

```
                 Time  Action     Name
0 2019-01-10 09:56:52  Opened      Max
2 2019-02-10 12:56:12  Closed    Susan
3 2019-02-10 13:02:58  Opened  Michael
```

Comment: @Manakin there is no second Michael in the text sample data.

Comment: @QuangHoang and Manakin Sorry my fault. Have changed it.